# How can I remove the duplicates libraries when using target_link_libraries in the CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to make several libraries(A,B,C libraries) to reduce the build time.

Through that, if I change files in A, I can build only A, neither B nor C.

I believe this is because I split the libraries.

By the way, when I add libraries, the "Eigen" libraries are duplicated in the A,B,C libraries.

I am worrying that the duplication would slow down my process and make burden.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/A.cpp
        )

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_FRICTION CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.cpp
        )


file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_DATA CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/C.cpp
        )

add_library(A STATIC ${SRC_FILES_A} )
add_library(B STATIC ${SRC_FILES_B} )
add_library(C STATIC ${SRC_FILES_C} )

find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(pinocchio REQUIRED)
find_package(qpSWIFT REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories(${pinocchio_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../thirdParty/)

target_include_directories(A PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC Eigen3::Eigen qpSWIFT ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(A PUBLIC -Wall )

target_include_directories(B PUBLIC ${YAML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC ${pinocchio_LIBRARIES}  Eigen3::Eigen ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(B PUBLIC -Wall )

target_include_directories(C PUBLIC ${YAML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(C PUBLIC ${pinocchio_LIBRARIES}  Eigen3::Eigen ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(C PUBLIC -Wall )
```

Will the duplication in the target_link_libraries make problems?

Is there any way to solve the duplication?

Comment: *Will the duplication in the target_link_libraries make problems?* No.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, duplication in target_link_libraries is not a problem at all, however if you still want to remove the duplicates from there you can do something like this.

```
set(TARGET_LIBS ${pinocchio_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND TARGET_LIBS Eigen3::Eigen ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES TARGET_LIBS)
```

The takeaway is [list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES <list>)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#remove-duplicates)